# why does vue stopped working after rendering 2 pages in cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I am extremely new to programming and i am trying to build a website with asp.net mvc.

after rendering a view page to _layout the vue in the _layout stopped working and the console shows this message

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'app' has already been declared (at (index):562:13)
```

I think it is caused by me applying vue scripts to both pages, but i really have no idea how to solve this situation with my very limited knowledge. i have the same code like the following for both cshtml files(_layout and the inner page)

```
const app = Vue.createApp({ 
   data() { return { }; }, 
   methods: { mymethodshere } })
.mount("#app");
```

Is there a way to get both pages running smoothly?

thanks for the help in advance.

I have tried to give use different id for the vue to mount, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the error stated, you have your Vue `app` twice in the page.

In `_layout` and somewhere else you have the same `app` variable.

```
const app = Vue.createApp
```

You can for example rename them to `app1` and `app2`.

```
const app1 = Vue.createApp
.mount("#app1");

const app2 = Vue.createApp
.mount("#app2");
```

Or you have to combine both to one Vue app.